NPM not installing and throwing errors when installing node.js
I've installed node.js several times in my system and is installed successfully but npm is throwing errors like:

I've tried a lot to fix this, please help!
The CMD error:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5247]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\DELL>node -v
v22.11.0

C:\Users\DELL>npm -v
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-prefix.js"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
10.9.0

C:\Users\DELL>

NPM is already set as an environment variable:

How should I fix this?
